# Ruby memory leaks

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, nokogiri

This is a parser that gem some html pages and scrape them, but it eat a lot of memory not being garbage collected.

This pass the result to a form. Here the memory usage happens.

Is there an obvious memory leaks in this code?

```
 def scrape(urls, item_selector)
    collection = []
    urls.each do |url|
      open(url) do |conn|
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(conn.read) # Opens URL
        @items = doc.css(item_selector)#[0..1] # Sets items
        @items = @items.map {|item| item['href']}
        @items.map{|item| Addressable::URI.parse(item).normalize }
        @items.map{|item| absolute_url(url, item) }
        @items.each do |item|
          open(item) do |connect|
            page = Nokogiri::HTML(connect.read)
            collection << {
              :url     => item,
              :title   => get_title(page),
              :price   => get_price(page),
              :image_url => get_image(page)
            }
          end # end connect
        end # end items
      end # end conn
    end #end urls
    collection
  end
```

Comment: Depending on the value of `item_selector` you might be keeping the whole tree in `@items` and returning it to the parent scope.

Comment: Side Note: `@items = @items.map` creates a new object, keeping the old one in the memory. `@items.map!` will edit the same object in place (no new object, no copy).

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We can't run your code because there are missing parts, and don't know how big a file you're parsing, but, in general, memory leaks aren't a problem dealing with Nokogiri or Ruby. You appear to be pulling in multiple pages as you parse, but without the minimal input data samples we can't tell what's really going on.

Comment: @the-tin-man Yes, sorry for my incompleteness.  because I'm ruby newbie, I wanted to discard some evident bug in my code, before go deeper.

Comment: Your use of `map` shows you don't understand the difference between `map` and `map!`. Your code could be simplified, but, without samples of input HTML we can't give detailed help, only broad suggestions. In general, you can't have a generic scraper function unless the pages being retrieved are all based on the template. Minor changes in HTML can break a scraper based on a single selector unless the page is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to Puma + Ruby >=2.1.x. fixed downgrading to ruby '2.0.0'.

Its not clear if its a memory leaks bugs or a Memory bloat. Anyway this combination is Memory prohibitive.

2 way are:

- Not use Puma (Webrick or Unicorn hasn't this issue with Ruby 2.3.1)
- Downgrade to Ruby 2.0.0

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/342

Comment: BTW, nothing related to Nokogiri, Imagemagic, fog gems, except that my code is memory intensive and fetching many pages at once.

Comment: You're aggregating data from pages in memory. If you're only doing a few pages that'd be one thing, but if you're doing a site, or multiple sites, it's not smart. Use a backing database to store the information you're capturing instead of `collection`. Even an on-disk SQLite DB would be capable of this. The Sequel ORM makes it really easy to work with it. See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Getting+Started. Puma and Unicorn are servers so they are not related to the problem, nor is the Ruby version the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you. You are right. However, this use case need a webserver, so this is the problem, not Nokogiri, nor parser process at all. It's a bug (or a problem) present any webapp. I thought it was related to scraping, but its not the case.